# Hover effect for only selected child's

Tags: html, css

I know that when I want to apply a hover effect to ALL divs inside a well I can use this code:

```css
.well:hover div {
  background-color:green
}
```

But now I want to apply the hover effect only to divs I wish inside this well. How can I specify them? I tried something like this:

`.well:hover div1,div2,div9 {}`

but that doesnt seem right. How to do it?

Comment: Selected divs, as in clicked divs? If so you can do `.well:hover div:focus`

Comment: @pol - No, sorry for the confusion, I mean divs I selected within the `well` that I want to give the special hover effect to.

Comment: I see. I've posted an answer, take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using comma, each entry is a separate selector:

So you should do it like this:

    `.well:hover div1,
    .well:hover div2,
    .well:hover div9 {
      /* your styles here */
    }`

Unless you are using a preprocessor, this can't be shortened.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not reading this right but you would just want to use `.well div:hover` as your css selector to apply individual hover effects to those divs.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the divs inside the well you want to affect and then add to css:

```
.well .my-hover-class:hover {
    /// do something
}
```